# How to schedule IIS SEO toolkit to run daily

Tags: windows, iis, seo, scheduling

I have installed Microsoft SEO Toolkit in IIS. http://www.iis.net/download/seotoolkit

I want to be able to schedule it to run daily and generate a report.

Does anybody know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in various ways :

1)**Using PowerShell Scripting** :
h t t p://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2008/02/10/using-microsoft-web-administration-in-windows-powershell.aspx

```
PS C:\ > $iis = new-object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
```

PS C:\ > $iis.Sites | foreach {
$*.Applications | where { $*.ApplicationPoolName -eq 'DefaultAppPool' } |
select-object Path,@{Name="AnonymousEnabled"; Expression = {
$_.GetWebConfiguration().GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication").GetAttributeValue("enabled")
}}
}

2) **You can set Create a small C# program like this** :

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Web.Management.SEO.Crawler;

namespace SEORunner {
    class Program {

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        if (args.Length != 1) {
            Console.WriteLine("Please specify the URL.");
            return;
        }

        // Create a URI class
        Uri startUrl = new Uri(args[0]);

        // Run the analysis
        CrawlerReport report = RunAnalysis(startUrl);

        // Run a few queries...
        LogSummary(report);

        LogStatusCodeSummary(report);

        LogBrokenLinks(report);
    }

    private static CrawlerReport RunAnalysis(Uri startUrl) {
        CrawlerSettings settings = new CrawlerSettings(startUrl);
        settings.ExternalLinkCriteria = ExternalLinkCriteria.SameFolderAndDeeper;
        // Generate a unique name
        settings.Name = startUrl.Host + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss");

        // Use the same directory as the default used by the UI
        string path = Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
            "IIS SEO Reports");

        settings.DirectoryCache = Path.Combine(path, settings.Name);

        // Create a new crawler and start running
        WebCrawler crawler = new WebCrawler(settings);
        crawler.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Processed - Remaining - Download Size");
        while (crawler.IsRunning) {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("{0,9:N0} - {1,9:N0} - {2,9:N2} MB",
                crawler.Report.GetUrlCount(),
                crawler.RemainingUrls,
                crawler.BytesDownloaded / 1048576.0f);
        }

        // Save the report
        crawler.Report.Save(path);

        Console.WriteLine("Crawling complete!!!");

        return crawler.Report;
    }

    private static void LogSummary(CrawlerReport report) {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(" Overview");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Start URL:  {0}", report.Settings.StartUrl);
        Console.WriteLine("Start Time: {0}", report.Settings.StartTime);
        Console.WriteLine("End Time:   {0}", report.Settings.EndTime);
        Console.WriteLine("URLs:       {0}", report.GetUrlCount());
        Console.WriteLine("Links:      {0}", report.Settings.LinkCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Violations: {0}", report.Settings.ViolationCount);
    }

    private static void LogBrokenLinks(CrawlerReport report) {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(" Broken links");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        foreach (var item in from url in report.GetUrls()
                             where url.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound &&
                                   !url.IsExternal
                             orderby url.Url.AbsoluteUri ascending
                             select url) {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }

    private static void LogStatusCodeSummary(CrawlerReport report) {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(" Status Code summary");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        foreach (var item in from url in report.GetUrls()
                             group url by url.StatusCode into g
                             orderby g.Key
                             select g) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,20} - {1,5:N0}", item.Key, item.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

}

And then configure to run it using windows scheduler

We are using the same toolkit at http://www.seo-genie.com and can run thouse tests for you on a weekly babys if you can ckeck this out or just use the code i had pasted above + windows sheduler , or maybe the is a way do so using Power Shell...

Answer (score 0):

I posted a blog entry on how you can build a Command line tool that uses the engine. You could then schedule it to run using the Task Scheduler in Windows.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2009/11/18/iis-seo-toolkit-start-new-analysis-automatically-through-code.aspx